# get links from dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

first of all I got this PHP code

```
<?php
$sqlget2 = "SELECT * FROM  `table` ORDER BY  `table`.`id` ASC ";
$sqldata2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlget2) or die('error getting data');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">Episode '.$row['id'].'</option>';
}?>
```

in my DB table I got 3 rows (id, stream_link, download_link)

My goal is to get the stream and download link of that id, that is selected in the dropdown right now.

I want the download link to go into a: a href="download_link"

and the stream link into a video tag

```
<video class="afterglow" id="myvideo" width="720" height="400" data-autoresize="fit">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use AJAX and use jQuery's change function with the `select` you have? So when the select is changed, you run your AJAX to request for the appropriate links

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please learn how to create a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your question does not show what you've tried, so you might consider checking the [what topics  can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help section.

Comment: my answer should work for you, you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mention you have the values in the DB.  And you're doing a SELECT * already, so there's no sense in going back to the DB, to fetch again, based on ID, when you already have that data available from the first fetch. So might as well use it, and make use of HTML5 data attributes.  Then use Jquery for the rest.

[WORKING EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/p4ha92x1/6/)

So echo the link/stream directly onto the option element, using data attributes. Like so...call them whatever you want.  I used data-link, and data-stream in this case.

```
<?php
 $sqlget2 = "SELECT * FROM  `table` ORDER BY  `table`.`id` ASC ";
 $sqldata2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlget2) or die('error getting data');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" data-link="'.$row['download_link'].'" 
 data-stream="'.$row['stream_link'].'" >Episode '.$row['id'].'</option>';
}?>
```

Then I would use Jquery to do the rest.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   // On select list change.     
   $('select').change(function(){

       // Find selected option element
       var opt = $(this).find(":selected");

       // Alter the download link href,  with the data-link attribute, on the option
       $('.download_link').attr('href',opt.data('link'));

       // Replace stream DIV, with data-stream attribute on the option
       $('#stream').html('<video controls autoplay class="afterglow" id="myvideo" width="720" 
          height="400" data-autoresize="fit"><source src="'+opt.data('stream')+'" type="video/mp4"></video>');

   });
});
```

Then on your HTML just have two elements under the select.  Where the data can be replaced into

```
   <a href='' class='download_link'>Download</a>

   <div id="stream"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The download works, but for the video I only get a pic. In your fiddle and also on my page.

Comment: Well thats probably because its not set to autoplay. If you just add "controls autoplay" to the video element, it should be good.  I've edited the answer to include it.  Also the fiddle as well.

Comment: Don't know if this is still a problem, but you'll probably have to call `afterglow.init()` after adding the player HTML to your DOM. This should initiate the player and make it work.

Answer (score -1):

First change this:

```
echo '<option id="selectedOption" value="'.$row['id'].'">Episode '.$row['id'].'</option>';
```

Then add an AJAX request (I'm using jQuery):

```
$('#select-div').on('change','#selectedOption',function() {
  let data = ('#selectedOption').val(),
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your/route.php',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
      //do something
    },
    error: function (result) {
      //do something 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is hardly an answer. Should be a comment

Comment: Yes I was't quite finished I thought someone else already answered it